# Poisson random variable using existing value

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a Possion random variable with $E[X]=\ln(2)$. Calculate $E[\cos(\pi*X)]$.

Comment: You can get the right font for $\cos$ and $\ln$ using `\cos` and `\ln`, respectively. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\cos\pi X]
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cos k\pi
\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}{k!}(-1)^k
\\
&=
\mathrm e^{-2\lambda}
\\
&=
\mathrm e^{-2\ln 2}
\\
&=
\frac14\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! This is really well organized and easy to understand.